# Should I Create New List of Lists or One function

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and Pandas. When I create many `DataFrame`s in one `list`, is it better to have different list and append in every step or just create them in one big function?

For example, I have a list of `DataFrame`s that have same columns, but different values and row numbers:

```
df_list = [[df1], [df2], [df3], [df5]]
```

Now I want to average each dataframe by a column's value:

```
df_list_1 = []
for df in df_list:
    new_df = df.groupby('col1').mean()
    df_list_1.append(new_df)
```

Next would be do some more calculation in each `df` of the `df_list_1`. Should I create another `df_list_2` in every step of calculation? What would be the best and fastest way to do this in python?

Comment: How about `pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4],axis=0,keys=['df1','df2','df3','df4'])`

Comment: @Wen I was reading about `concat` , however, when I do calculations to in some columns of each `df` how could this be helpful to calculations?

Comment: do DF.loc['df1'] before you calculation

Comment: @Wen isn't `df.loc` for locating the specific row? also, my original question was to whether or not to create new lists each time? or is there any other efficient way to do calculations in each dataframe inside a list?

Comment: Just try this .`New_DF=DF.groupby([DF.index.get_level_values(0),'col1']).mean()`, I will make it to a answer

Comment: @Wen how do I iterate each `df` in this from the list? So, I can get into each df? is list comprehension good? i

Comment: I post it as an answer

Comment: `list` is good way for restore different `DataFrame`(not the same shape), but if they all have the same column , it is better to use `multiple index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data input :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1.0, 2.3,0.2,0.53], [2, 3.35, 2.0,0.2,0.65], [2,3.4,
               2.0,0.25,0.55], [3,3.4,2.0,0.25,0.55]],
               columns=["ID", "NaX", "OO","OO1","OO2"])\
               .set_index('Sample_ID')#sampleData

DF=pd.concat([df1,df1,df1,df1],axis=0,keys=['df1','df2','df3','‌​df4'])
NEW_DF=DF.groupby([DF.index.get_level_values(0),'NaX']).mean()
NEW_DF
Out[100]: 
          OO    OO1   OO2
    NaX                  
df1 1.00  2.3  0.20  0.53
    3.35  2.0  0.20  0.65
    3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
df2 1.00  2.3  0.20  0.53
    3.35  2.0  0.20  0.65
    3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
df3 1.00  2.3  0.20  0.53
    3.35  2.0  0.20  0.65
    3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
df4 1.00  2.3  0.20  0.53
    3.35  2.0  0.20  0.65
    3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
```

Comment: this is good! works! thanks! I don't have enough points to upvote, but you get one for effort :)

Comment: glad this help ~also prepare for future : `list` is good way for restore different `DataFrame`(not the same shape), but if they all have the same column , it is better to use multiple index